# postfix ignores transport map when relaying from local servers

Tags: postfix-mta

I have a central **server** with postfix, relayhost to my mail provider.
I do not want to enter his credentials into all other local systems (**satellites**), so I want them to use **server** for relaying.

Let's say my domain is **mydomain.de**. **server** sends all mails to the mail provider instead of trying to deliver them locally because I said so in the transport map:
`mydomain.de smtp:smtps.udag.de:587`

That part works.
**satellites** also send mail to any other E-Mail-address via **server**. Only if a **satellite** sends to xx@ymdomain.de, **server** ignores the transport map and tries to deliver locally.

How could I fix this?